Can't use the new Modifier.animateItem()
I want to use the new Modifier.animateItem() API, announced here and here to animate item (dis)appearance inside a LazyColumn, however it is impossible for me to import it. I've added "androidx.compose.animation:animation:1.7.0-alpha06" to my dependencies and tried using it from within a LazyListScope, but AndroidStudio can't find it. Am I missing something?

You don't need to import it because it is not a top-level function. It is a member function of LazyItemScope, so whenever you have such an object you just call animateItem on it. In practice that looks a bit different because you need an additional Modifier receiver object.
Usually it will look something like this:
LazyColumn {
    items(listOfItems) {
        Box( // or whatever you use to display an item
            modifier = Modifier.animateItem(),
        )
    }
}

The items lambda provides a LazyItemScope so now you can use Modifier to call animateItem which will use both these receiver objects.
Note that the animateItem is not applied to the LazyColumn. It is also not available in the LazyColumn's lambda (which provides a LazyListScope). It is only available in the various item and items lambdas that provide a LazyItemScope.

I had already tried it in that way, however your very fair point of animateItem() actually being part of LazyItemScope and therefore the androidx.compose.foundation:foundation package gave me the idea to include version 1.7.0-alpha06 of that explicitly, which resolved the issue. Previously it was only transitively included through androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.7.0-alpha06 or some other compose dependency I guess, which in turn doesn't seem to use the foundation package of the same version for some reason.

Here's a tiny update: it's now in beta! androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.7.0-beta02

The animateItem modifier was added in version 1.7.0 of the androidx.compose.foundation:foundation artifact, as stated in their Android API reference here. Just add the following dependency, and you should be good to go.
Groovy
implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.7.0"

Kotlin
implementation("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.7.0")

